# Showing data values (subtotal?) on normal bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I wish to show the subtotal only.. The problem I am facing is it got a bunch of value pop out all together...

Reproducible Data :

```
df.mpg <- mpg[mpg$manufacturer == "audi", ]
```

the below is my command :

```
gp.mpg <- ggplot(df.mpg, aes(x = trans, y=hwy)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "navy", alpha = 0.5) + 
  labs( title = "",
        x = "",
        y = "") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = hwy),size = 3,  vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5, position = "identity" )
  
gp.mpg
```

[image]

Although I have try something other than this such as `position = "identity"`, searching around in Youtube but still not able to solve... need help..

Also, here is the `dput(df.mpg)`

```
> dput(df.mpg)
structure(list(manufacturer = c("audi", "audi", "audi", "audi", 
"audi", "audi", "audi", "audi", "audi", "audi", "audi", "audi", 
"audi", "audi", "audi", "audi", "audi", "audi"), model = c("a4", 
"a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4 quattro", "a4 quattro", 
"a4 quattro", "a4 quattro", "a4 quattro", "a4 quattro", "a4 quattro", 
"a4 quattro", "a6 quattro", "a6 quattro", "a6 quattro"), displ = c(1.8, 
1.8, 2, 2, 2.8, 2.8, 3.1, 1.8, 1.8, 2, 2, 2.8, 2.8, 3.1, 3.1, 
2.8, 3.1, 4.2), year = c(1999L, 1999L, 2008L, 2008L, 1999L, 1999L, 
2008L, 1999L, 1999L, 2008L, 2008L, 1999L, 1999L, 2008L, 2008L, 
1999L, 2008L, 2008L), cyl = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L), trans = c("auto(l5)", 
"manual(m5)", "manual(m6)", "auto(av)", "auto(l5)", "manual(m5)", 
"auto(av)", "manual(m5)", "auto(l5)", "manual(m6)", "auto(s6)", 
"auto(l5)", "manual(m5)", "auto(s6)", "manual(m6)", "auto(l5)", 
"auto(s6)", "auto(s6)"), drv = c("f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", 
"f", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), 
    cty = c(18L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 20L, 
    19L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 16L), hwy = c(29L, 29L, 
    31L, 30L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 26L, 25L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
    25L, 24L, 25L, 23L), fl = c("p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", 
    "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p"
    ), class = c("compact", "compact", "compact", "compact", 
    "compact", "compact", "compact", "compact", "compact", "compact", 
    "compact", "compact", "compact", "compact", "compact", "midsize", 
    "midsize", "midsize")), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The total for each bar? Dont you need to aggregate?

Comment: Please make the question reproducible: include the output of `dput(df)` .

Comment: Hi @Peter , thank you for the tips... I have edited with a reproducible output, and dput(df.mpg) in this case.. thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)



df.mpg.summarized <- df.mpg %>%
  group_by(trans) %>%
  ##sum or mean... choice is yours
  summarise(total_hwy = sum(hwy)) 

# Plot the summarized data..
gp.mpg <- ggplot(df.mpg.summarized, aes(x = trans, y = total_hwy)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "navy", alpha = 0.5) +
  labs(title = "your cool title",
       x = "Transmission Type",
       y = "Total Highway Mileage") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = total_hwy), vjust = -0.5, size = 3)  # labeling with the total hwy...

# I'm in vsc :'( 
plot(gp.mpg)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Hey @AltunE ! Thank you!! It is really what I want. and I am deeply appreciate it. Do allow me to ask you one more question... 

If I wish to overview the overall all manufacturer in bar chart (such as by using `facet_wrap ()` ) , I can execute the code below like that right? :

`df_manufacturer.summarized <- df_mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer, trans) %>%
  summarise(total_hwy = sum(hwy))`

etc

Anyway, does VSC means like Voluntary Separation Scheme? :'(

Comment: hello hello @Gambit sorry for the late response... Yes, you're on the right track for creating a faceted bar chart that shows the total highway mileage for each transmission type, separated by the manufacturer... After summarizing, you can add + facet_wrap(~ manufacturer) to your ggplot code to create separate panels for each manufacturer.  if you have further questions don't hesitate to ask I will try to help (if I can lol XD ) and VSC is visual studio code :=)  (in Rstudio you don't have to use print, plots, etc ;=) )